# I am unable to show the access denied message of the premium content module. How can I do this?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, status-messages

I have 3 view modes (teaser, presentation and full view mode). I have created a `node--content-type.tpl.php` and created the code for each view mode using a conditional statement

```
if($teaser) {} 
else if($node->type == 'tu_mooc' && $view_mode == 'presentation') {} 
else {}
```

I have linked the 3 view modes. So I can go from the teaser to the presentation and from the presentation to the full view mode.

I have downloaded the premium content module so that access to the full view mode is limited to authenticated users. I made a small change in `premium.module` so that anonymous users have access to both the teaser view mode and the presentation view mode. The problem I have is that when I try to access the full view mode (as an anonymous user) I don't get the access denied message. Instead I get the code that appears within the teaser view mode. i.e. In node/1 I get the teaser of node1 instead of getting the access denied message.

Do I need to include some code like `<?php print $denied_message; ?>` into the `node--content-type.tpl.php?` or what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included this code within the teaser in node--content-type.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $content['body'][0]['#markup']; ?>
```

And I have included this code in template.php:

```
function  mimooc_premium_body($arguments) {
  $node = $arguments['node'];
  node_build_content($node, 'teaser');
  unset($node->content['links']);
  $level = premium_level_load($node->premium);
  if ($level->denied_message) {
    $denied_message = $level->denied_message;
    $denied_message_format = $level->denied_message_format;
  }
  else {
    $denied_message = variable_get('premium_message', t('Full text available to premium subscribers only.'));
    $denied_message_format = variable_get('premium_format');
  }
  // Only display the premium message, if we actual have any content.
  if (!empty($node->content)) {
    return '<div class="premium-message"><h3>' . check_markup($denied_message, $denied_message_format) . '</h3><p>' . l('Click here to sign in', 'user') . '</p></div>';
  }
}
```

Now, when I access the full view mode of the node, I get the teaser of that node with the access denied message.